# Azure Mobile Services Latency

Tags: rest, azure

I am noticing latency in REST data the first time I visit a web site that is being served via Azure Mobile Services. Is there a cache or timeout of a connection after a set amount of time, because I am worried about user experience while waiting 7-8 seconds for the data to load (and there is not a lot of data, as I am testing 10 records returned). Once the first connection is made, subsequent visits appear to load quickly... but if I don't visit the site for a while, we are back to 7-8 seconds on first load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reason:** The reason for this latency is the *"shared" mode*. When the first call to the service is made, it performs a "cold start" (initializing and starting the virtual server etc)
As you described in your question, after a while when the service is not used, it is put into the "sleep mode" again.

**Solution:** If you do not want this waiting-time, you can set your service to *"reserved" mode*, which forces the service to be active all time even when you do not access it for a while. But be aware that this requires you to pay some extra fees.